# Is boolean return type allowed in C?

Tags: c, boolean

When I try to compile a function with return type `bool` in GCC compiler, the compiler throws me this error.

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘comp’
```

But when I change the return type to `int`, it is getting compiled successfully.

The function is as below.

```
bool comp(struct node *n1,struct node *n2)
{
    if(n1 == NULL || n2 == NULL)
    return false;
    while(n1 != NULL && n2 != NULL)
    {
        if(n1->data == n2->data)
        { n1=n1->link; n2=n2->link; }
        else
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Here I am comparing two linked lists. Is bool return type supported in C or not?

Comment: If both n1 and n2 are NULL, you would probably want to return true.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`bool` does not exist as a keyword pre-C99.

In C99, it should work, but as @pmg points out below, it's still not a keyword.  It's a macro declared in `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: +1 `bool` is a typedef (in `<stdbool.h>`) to the C99 keyword, and predefined type, `_Bool`.

Comment: bool is not a keyword in C99 either, it is a macro defined by <stdbool.h>, which you need to include if you want to use it. (Oh, someone said this while I was looking things up to verify, and I forgot to refresh. Sorry for the duplication.)

Comment: Thx for your answer. That clarified my doubt. +1.

Answer (score 16):

try to include:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
void main(){
    bool x = true;
    if(x)
        printf("Boolean works in 'C'. \n");
    else
        printf("Boolean doesn't work in 'C'. \n");
}
```

Comment: Kindly Add some content

Answer (score 1):

a way to do a manual bool

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int bool;

bool comp(struct node *n1,struct node *n2)
{
    if(n1 == NULL || n2 == NULL)
    return(false);
    while(n1 != NULL && n2 != NULL)
    {
        if(n1->data == n2->data)
        { n1=n1->link; n2=n2->link; }
        else
            return(false);

    }
    return true;
```

ie it is returning 1 or 0, but amiably you get as true and false;

After all a bool is a 1 or 0